# How to use Gnome Lockscreen instead of xscreensaver Lockscreen

Tags: fedora, gnome, screensaver, xscreensaver

I am using Xscreensaver in my Fedora 28. I was using it only because Apple Aerial Screensaver can be added as a screensaver to it.

But the login screen of xscreensaver is ugly and doesnt go with the Apple Aerial Screensaver.
Is there any way to change the xscreensaver Lock Screen to default Gnome Lock ?

Comment: Just to clarify the situation, you're using the Gnome DE;  the Apple Aerial screensaver can't be added to the Gnome screensaver so you're using Xscreensaver?  And you want replace Xscreensaver's lock screen with Gnome's lock screen?  Have you explored using Xscreensaver only as a screensaver, and using Gnome's lock screen for locking?

Comment: @fixer1234 Apple aerial screensaver can't be added to Gnome screensaver hence the xscreensaver. I tried your method too( Xscreensaver as screensaver and then locking with Gnome's Lockscreen). But Gnome lockscreen will kill the screensaver once it locks.